# Ubuntu 19.04 Hidden Files are not being shown - how to fix it

Tags: command-line, filesystem, 19.04

I am trying to display all the hidden files on my home file.

I have attempted to display this by selecting "Show Hidden Files" checkbox but this does not work.

Am I missing something or can a terminal entry be ran to fix this?

Comment: just to be sure, what is the output of `ls -la ~` command.

Comment: @rɑːdʒɑ, managed to get the issue sorted by running the following: (initramfs) prompt, type fsck -f /dev/sda1 to check/repair your file system.         Shows the hidden files now.

Comment: Glad your issue solved.